# Autorefresh XML data in SWF Action Script 2.0

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-2, flash-cs4, flashlite

So I am working on a SWF using AS 2.0. It needs to access exchange rates from an XML file. I already have a setInterval that iterates through XML child nodes. So I already have a timer running in my code. I need to set another timer in order to reload the XML so that changes to the XML are constantly updated say every 20 seconds. When I try to do that the timers overlap. Can you guys help??  Thanks

**Here is my current code:**

```
    var index:Number = 0;
    var myxml:XML = new XML();
    myxml.ignoreWhite = true;
    myxml.onLoad = function(success:Boolean):Void{
loadData();
setInterval(loadData, 3000);
};


function loadData(){
var messages:XMLNode = myxml.firstChild;
if(index >= messages.childNodes.length)
    index = 0;
var my_message:XMLNode = messages.childNodes[index];

_root.status_1.htmlText = my_message.childNodes[0].firstChild.nodeValue; 
_root.status_2.htmlText = my_message.childNodes[1].firstChild.nodeValue; 
_root.status_3.htmlText = my_message.childNodes[2].firstChild.nodeValue; 
_root.status_4.htmlText = my_message.childNodes[3].firstChild.nodeValue;
_root.status_5.htmlText = my_message.childNodes[4].firstChild.nodeValue;
_root.status_6.htmlText = my_message.childNodes[5].firstChild.nodeValue;        

index++;

       }
myxml.load("data.xml");
```

**MY XML File looks like this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <messages>
 <message>
            <item>1.38329</item>
    <item>1.58344</item>
    <item>1.06960</item>
    <item>93.7300</item>
    <item>0.9864</item>
    <item></item>
</message>


<message >
    <item>1.36789</item>
    <item>1.56734</item>
    <item>1.03752</item>
    <item>93.7267</item>
    <item>0.97836</item>
    <item></item>
</message>

<message >
    <item>1.38126</item>
    <item>1.59104</item>
    <item>1.05380</item>
    <item>93.5755</item>
    <item>0.9923</item>
    <item></item>
</message>

<message >
    <item>1.38126</item>
    <item>1.29789</item>
    <item>1.5423</item>
    <item>1.07123</item>
    <item>93.7268</item>
    <item>0.9867</item>
    <item></item>
</message>

<message >  
    <item>1.38329</item>
    <item>1.514762</item>
    <item>1.07451</item>
    <item>93.7277</item>
    <item>0.9975</item>
      <item></item> 
</message>

</messages>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest the following code :

```
var iCurrentNodeLoading:Number;
var intervalNextNode:Number;
var intervalReloadXML:Number;

var myxml:XML = new XML();
myxml.ignoreWhite = true;
myxml.onLoad = mx.utils.Delegate.create(this, onXMLLoadedEvent);

function onXMLLoadedEvent(success:Boolean):Void{
  if (success) {
    iCurrentNodeLoading = 0;
    loadNextNode();
  }
};


function loadNextNode() {
  if (intervalNextNode != undefined) clearInterval(intervalNextNode);
  var messages:XMLNode = myxml.firstChild;
  if (iCurrentNodeLoading >= messages.childNodes.length) iCurrentNodeLoading = 0;

  var my_message:XMLNode = messages.childNodes[iCurrentNodeLoading];

  _root.status_1.htmlText = my_message.childNodes[0].firstChild.nodeValue; 
  _root.status_2.htmlText = my_message.childNodes[1].firstChild.nodeValue; 
  _root.status_3.htmlText = my_message.childNodes[2].firstChild.nodeValue; 
  _root.status_4.htmlText = my_message.childNodes[3].firstChild.nodeValue;
  _root.status_5.htmlText = my_message.childNodes[4].firstChild.nodeValue;
  _root.status_6.htmlText = my_message.childNodes[5].firstChild.nodeValue;        

  iCurrentNodeLoading++;
  intervalNextNode = setInterval(loadNextNode, 3000);
}

function reloadXML(){
  if (intervalReloadXML != undefined) clearInterval(intervalReloadXML);
  myxml.load("data.xml");
  intervalNextNode = setInterval(reloadXML, 20000);
}

reloadXML();
```